# SharedPreferences Saving

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, drawable, android-drawable, imagebutton

I am creating an app where the user can change the source image of several ImageButtons, and I am saving these in SharedPreferences. Here are my methods for getting and saving the images:

```
public int getImage(String item){
        SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int id = pref.getInt(item, R.drawable.no_item);
        return id;
    }

public void saveImage(String item, int resourceId){
        SharedPreferences starterSP = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = starterSP.edit();
        edit.putInt(item, resourceId);
        edit.apply();
    }
```

These images are stored as Drawable ID's, which are stored as integers.

However, when I add a new image file to my drawable folder and relaunch the app, all of my existing ImageButton sources are changed to some other image in my Drawable folder. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

**You should save `drawable` name instead of id because, `drawable` id will change , every time the app compiles.**

You can get drawable resource id by drawable name using -

```
final int rsId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageNameFromPreferences, "drawable", 
       context.getPackageName());
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, imageNameFromPreferences is the key I use to store the value in SharedPreferences, and "drawable" is the actual name (such as "R.drawable.example")?

Comment: No. you should save just `example` in `R.drawable.example`, i.e. `example` is your `drawable` name.

Answer (score 0):

Save drawable name instead of id because the name of a drawable does not change when new drawables are added to the project and use the name to retrieve id.

```
 public Int getImage(String item) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String drawable_name = pref.getString(item, null);
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imageNameFromPreferences, drawable_name, 
        context.getPackageName());
        return id;
    }

public void saveImage(String item, String drawable_name) {
        SharedPreferences starterSP = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = starterSP.edit();
        edit.putString(item, drawable_name);
        edit.apply();
    }
```